# Prompt for password when mysql client reconnects

Tags: mysql, security

I am invoking mysql through the following :

```
mysql -h localhost -u user -p db
```

This will lead to the user being prompted to enter the password.

However I have set the interactive_timeout to 60 secs.

After 60 sec, the client will timeout but since the reconnect option is not set to false hence it will try to reconnect.
While reconnect, the mysql client does not prompt for password.
I want to make it prompt for password while reconnecting.
Can anyone help me on this.

Here is the sample output

```
mysql -h localhost -u user -p db 
Enter password: 
Reading table information for completion of table and column names
You can turn off this feature to get a quicker startup with -A

Welcome to the MySQL monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MySQL connection id is 26
Server version: 5.1.58 MySQL Community Server (GPL)

Copyright (c) 2000, 2010, Oracle and/or its affiliates. All rights reserved.
This software comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY. This is free software,
and you are welcome to modify and redistribute it under the GPL v2 license

Type 'help;' or '\h' for help. Type '\c' to clear the current input statement.

mysql> show variables;
ERROR 2006 (HY000): MySQL server has gone away
No connection. Trying to reconnect...
Connection id:    30
Current database: db
```

I want it to prompt for password while reconnecting

Answer (score 0):

You could try seeing if [aliasing](http://linux.about.com/library/glossary/bldef_alias.htm) `mysql` to specify [--skip-reconnect](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/mysql-command-options.html#option_mysql_reconnect) (in conjunction with `interactive_timeout`) would work